# Access Cloudformation Parameters From Java Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function with environment variables defined like the following in the cloud formation template.

```
Parameters:
  Parameter1: { Type: String }
Resources:
 LambdaFunction:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
   Properties:
     FunctionName: "Function"
     CodeUri: // relevant parameters
     Handler: handler::handlerequest 
    Role: //Role
    Runtime: java8
    Timeout: 300
  Environment:
    Variables:
      refParamter1:
        Ref: Parameter1
```

My code for the handle request is as follows:

```
String referenceParameter = System.getenv("refParamter1");
System.out.println("Referenced Paramter "+ referenceParameter );
```

When I deploy this and trigger my lambda it gives me the `null` for the printed `referenceParameter`.

Is using `System.getenv` incorrect when referencing environment variables in lambda?

There is a similar question : [CloudFormation - Access Parameter from Lambda Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707808/cloudformation-access-parameter-from-lambda-code) for python but doesn't give any answer for Java

This is the question with the answer which suggests to use `System.getenv` : [Accessing AWS Lambda environment variables in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094954/accessing-aws-lambda-environment-variables-in-java-code)

Comment: System.getenv is the right way...do you see the variable in the lambda console of AWS after deploying?

Comment: No. It was not there in the console. I figured out that the problem was with the indenting of the yml where ```Environment``` is defined. Once the indentation is fixed the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct you are trying to reference a parameter from the resource, then your syntax is wrong, try this:

```
  Environment:
    Variables:
      refParamter1: !Ref Parameter1
```

The environment variables definition is an array of key:value, you can see the documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html

When deploying make sure to go to the lambda console and check that it correctly appears under environments variables in your function UI, and then you can use:

```
String referenceParameter = System.getenv("refParamter1");
```

To access your variable.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The indentation was wrong in the Lambda function and the yml depends on the indentation it has not taken the environment variables into account.

```
Parameters:
  Parameter1: { Type: String }
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "Function"
      CodeUri: // relevant parameters
      Handler: handler::handlerequest 
      Role: //Role
      Runtime: java8
      Timeout: 300
      Environment:
        Variables:
          refParamter1:
            Ref: Parameter1
```